# Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} g_n(x) = g(x)$ where $g_n(x)$ is the inverse function of $f_n(x) = f(x) + \frac{1}{n}x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing continuous function,

Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} g_n(x) = g(x)$ where $g_n(x)$ is the inverse function of $f_n(x) = f(x) + \frac{1}{n}x$ and $g(x)$ is the inverse function of $f(x)$.

---

$g_n(x) = f_n(x)^{-1} = nx - ng(x)$ (Is this correct?) this alone does not seem to imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = g(x)$. So I'm thinking that there is some property for the limits of the inverse function, so that we can use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$.

Edit: My inverse function is incorrect, as pointed out by Dominic in the comments, how should I go about inverting $f_n$?

Comment: $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, yes. I should've added that to the post. Will edit.

Comment: Your inverse function is wrong. for example when $ f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} ; x\mapsto x$ then $f_n(x)= \frac{n+1}{n}x $ and $g_n(x)=\frac{n}{n+1} x$

Comment: You don't need to calculate the inverse explicitly. Think about this: fix $x_0 \in R$. We clearly have $f_n(x_0) - f(x_0) = \frac{x_0}{n}$. Using the continuity of $f$, can you find a way to bound $|g_n(x_0) - g(x_0)|$? The main idea is that the "perturbations" $\frac{x}{n}$ applied to $f(x)$ become less and less important as $n$ grows, and by continuity, the same is true for the difference between $g(x)$ and $g_n(x)$. But you need some $\epsilon - \delta$ work to make this rigorous.